# Is it possible to store all bytes from file to array of bytes?

Tags: java, memory, arrays

Just as the title, is it possible to store all bytes from file to array of bytes without getting java heap space error?

Comment: Basically yes, however, if file size is greater than heap size then an OOME will occur.

Comment: As long as the JVM has enough memory, yes. If not, no.

Comment: Since you put no limits on either value, there can be no answer to your question.

Comment: Have you tried it? You mention an error, so did you try this and are getting that error? If so, you should post the relevant code, and the stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use [`IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29)
 to store it.

also, if its a big file, you can increase java heap space by executing it with vm arguments:

```
java -Xmx6g myprogram
```

or

```
java -jar -Xmx6g myprogram.jar
```

the `6g` means 6 Gigabytes of heap

Comment: There is no need for an external dependency: `Files.readAllBytes(path)` has been part of the JDK since Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by assylias, the 100% Java way to do this is with `Files.readAllBytes(path)`.

Heap space errors depend on the file size and the amount of free memory in the JVM heap; you need to verify that the first is lower than the second before reading it:

```
File file = new File(path);
bytes[] bytes;
if (file.length > Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) {
    // warn about reading
} else {
    bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path)
    // do stuff with 'bytes'
}
```